# AWS - How to allow only ip addresses from only a specific country to access EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to block all ip addresses accessing my EC2 instance through RDP/SSH from all other countries except the local country. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Be aware that anyone can get a free VPN service and seem to connect from your country. Geo filtering can help, but not against a determined attacker.

Comment: Rather than restricting by geography, it would be advisable to only allow known IP addresses access to RDP/SSH. Even permitting access from a single country is too "open" for maintaining good security.

Answer (score 1):

EC2 security does not provide this functionality out of the box, but you can use other utilities to restrict access base on location.

you can try [ssh-geoip-filter](https://github.com/CristianCantoro/ssh-geoip-filter) that work like charm all you need to specify allowed countries in the ssh filter.

```
# UPPERCASE space-separated country codes to ACCEPT
ALLOW_COUNTRIES='US DE IT AT CH NL PK ES US'
```

Another option is that you cam check [pam_geoip-restrict-accounts-to-certain-citiescountrys-only](https://blog.grimneko.de/2012/03/01/pam_geoip-restrict-accounts-to-certain-citiescountrys-only/)